# CSS transition of width of inline-block element with variable width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have an inline-block element that has p tag with variable width ( p tag text and thus its width is dynamically set with script. ) 
How can i use css transition for width so change of text and width is nice and with animation and not abrupt.
I made a simplified pen of what i mean:
http://codepen.io/lukaMis/pen/azXjzm

```
#my-element {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 180, 255);
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
}
```

tnx
Have a nice day
Luka

Comment: None of the browsers handle CSS transition from/to auto values correctly for now, you need to do it with javascript.

Comment: Tnx Mat.
I ended up hiding p tag, calculating its width after text update and using that for new min-width of wrapping element that is than css transitioned. It is a hack but looks nice.